# Intermittent token failure with load balanced oAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, load-balancing

We have implemented our own oAuth provider and are having an issue when the system runs in a load balanced scenario.  When we run with a single server all is well but when we switch the other on we get the following situation:

- Token ‘A’ generated on server 1
- Token ‘A’ not valid on server 2.

I have done some Googling on this and it seems to be a known issue but can’t seem to find a solution.

Anybody got an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make sure that you do one of:

- synchronize the state of your Authorization Server between all load balanced nodes by using a shared cache (e.g. database or file system) or replicates state across nodes using some replication mechanism
- your Authorization Server issues tokens that can be inspected by the load balancer to find out to which node it needs to send the validation request

The latter. has the downside that it cannot be used in a high availability scenario.

Comment: Thanks will investigate